# Does VueJS have access to the system enviroment variables

Tags: vue.js, environment-variables

This question is ***not*** about `.env` files, thank you.

It says in the [docs](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#environment-variables):

> In addition, environment variables that already exist when Vue CLI is executed have the 
>   highest priority and will not be overwritten by .env files.

Well, I added a system variable VUE_APP_TEST = "test value"

And then rebuild an application adding following code

```js
console.log(process.env.VUE_APP_TEST)
```

To no avail, obviously

So the question is, am I doing something wrong, or just overestimating VueJS capabilities, or docs are wrong, or I am misunderstanding the "already existing variables" part?

**UPDATE:**

Yes, I stoped the `npm run dev` and started it again before asking this question. It works well for variables in `.env` files. But the question is not about the `.env` files.

Restarting the system did help. But this is beyond my understanding why vue-cli didn't catch changes in the environment any other way. Should've checked if it's actually a vue-cli issue or is it windows who don't update the environment until restart (weird).

Comment: Did you restart your terminal after adding this variable?

Comment: In this particular case, I'm working under Windows, so the only thing I can restart is the system itself, but wouldn't that be overkill? Also, I don't remember restarting a terminal under Ubuntu, adding a variable worked just fine.

Comment: I think restarting the terminal would work. kill the ongoing serve process and then run npm run vue-cli-service serve or whatever you have mentioned in your script object in package.json file

Comment: No, restarting the terminal didn't help. OTOH, restarting the system did.

Comment: Windows has a terminal.  In this case he was likely referring to the terminal-like command prompt, essentially asking you to terminate the `npm run serve` batch job and restart it.  The reason is that hot reloading isn't enough to activate .env changes

Comment: I know this, right, and this was the first thing I did. Perhaps I just put it wrong but it *is* in the question.